# No email notifications being triggered after a successful CT test purchase with SagePay

Tags: cartthrob

After a successful test transaction with SagePay no email is triggered for admin or the customer. Also I cannot get the status change trigger to work either. Although the low stock trigger does work, so I know that emails in general are working ok.

I have checked that the email is stored correctly in the customer info tag (before being sent to SagePay) and it is. But the emails are not even being logged in the CT email logs.

Also, when I return from SagePay (and get the successful page with correct info etc) the cart still has items in it, so it's not being cleared as it should. I'm sure it's all related to something simple maybe?

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my own silly mistake causing the issues here, whoops!

In the successful transaction email notifications I was using {exp:cartthrob:order_subtotal} as opposed to {exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal}. This caused problems with the transaction authorisation process.

After talking through with Chris @ CartThorb, he realised my mistake. After changing the tags to the correct version all was OK.

Hopefully this will help someone else at some point!

Thanks for the great support Chris.